How to compare string to date laravel mongodb using whereRaw?
I'm trying to use whereRaw with mongodb
$soa_list->where('status', 'FOR OP REQUEST')
         ->whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE(validity, '%Y-%m-%d') >= ?", Carbon::now());

but  I'm getting this error
$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects

My validity is string for example 'January 1, 2024 and I want it to convert first to be able to compare it to todays date.

Please look at your question and try to improve it. I see you got an answer, and you are trying to explain there what you mean here. Please update your question so that everyone can understand it from the question only, without having to look at all your comments at every (also future) answer
